# How to click on an image using selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium, unable to click on image named "Register" which is highlighted in attached screenshot.Can anyone let me know why the web element is not being identified on run time and what can be done to identify and click on it?

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;    
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;    
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Registration {

    public WebDriver driver1;
    public String exepath="C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe";
    public String filepath="C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\Desktop\\Book1tetsts.xls";
    public FileInputStream file;
    public String userID;
    public String password;
    public String Fname;
    public String Lname;
    private Object wait;

    @Test
    void formfilling() throws BiffException, IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        file = new FileInputStream(filepath);
        Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(file);
        Sheet sh = wb.getSheet(0); // this is to get the access to Sheet1. 
        userID= sh.getCell(0,0).getContents();
        password= sh.getCell(1,0).getContents();
        Fname= sh.getCell(2,0).getContents();
        Lname=sh.getCell(3,0).getContents();

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exepath);
        driver1= new ChromeDriver();        
        driver1.get("http://www.esevaonline.telangana.gov.in");
        synchronized (driver1) {
            driver1.wait(15000);
        }     

        driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lhsNav']/a/img[@src='images/register2.gif']")).click();
        //UserID
        driver1.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/center/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/center/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(userID);
        //Password
        driver1.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/center/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/center/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(password);
        //Re-Type Password
        driver1.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/center/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/center/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(password);
        driver1.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/center/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/center/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(Fname);
        //LastName
        driver1.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/center/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/center/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys(Lname);
        //DOB


    }
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0L4f.jpg)

Comment: If u want click using image mns u can try with skilui else switch to frame and click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given "Register" img is inside frame . So you **need to switch frame** first then performe any event on webelement which are inside that frame.

Please add below line of code in ur code.

```
     driver1.switchTo().frame("mainFrame"); // switch frame 

        driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='lhsNav']/a/img[@src='images/register2.gif']")).click();
        //UserID

// other operation
```

Hope this help you :)

Comment: @swathi please accept the answer so other can get help from it

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!! :) it is working fine now.Can you kindly let me know how to identify when an element is in frame?

Comment: Yes just you need to check HTML code of that web page .. in that if u see any webelement is inside any <frameset> or <frame> or <iframe> tag then u need to switch inside that frame then perform any operation on those webelement .. n do accept my answers by check ✓ sign